# Better option for image upload (cloud) in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, forms, next.js, cloudinary

I'm currently developing my first real project for a client with NextJS and MongoDB and I'm having problems uploading images. I'm working with Cloudinary but it can't receive multiple files and I'm also having issues with state management because when the form is submitted my database doesn't receive the files whereas Cloudinary does.

The API works fine so I post here the code of the form (REACT).

```
  export default function NewProduct() {
  const initialState = {
    title: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    content: "",
    images: [],
    category: "tortas",
  };

  const [product, setProduct] = useState(initialState);
  const { title, price, description, content, category } = product;

  const [files, setFile] = useState("");


  //const handleChangeInput = (e) => {
  //  setProduct({ ...product, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  //};

  const handleUploadInput = async (e) => {
    const uploadFiles = [...e.target.files];
    setFile([...files, uploadFiles]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let file of files) {
      formData.append("file", file);
    }

    formData.append("upload_preset", "balbla");

    const res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/blabla/image/upload",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    setProduct((p) => ({ ...p, images: data.secure_url}));
    await createProduct();
    setProduct(initialState);
  };

  const createProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(product),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.formDiv}>
        <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          
          
          <input
            type="file"
            name="file"
            onChange={handleUploadInput}
            multiple
            accept="image/*"
          />
          
          
          <button type="submit">Crear</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

In case using Cloudinary isn't the best option with NextJS, what other cloud or stuff I could use?
I hope I made myself clear.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [Cloudinary Upload API endpoint](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload) would accept only 1 file at a time. You can check the [Cloudinary sample react project here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react/tree/master/samples/photo_album) for some example implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloudinary Upload API unfortunately doesn't support uploading multiple resources within a single request, so you would need to likely loop through all of your media items and upload them each individually.

As far as the production creation is concerned, I can't tell for sure, but you may be trying to create the product before your product state is updated.

Inside `createProduct` have you checked to see if all of the data you expect is available at the time it's being ran?

You could try listening to updates to the `product` state and create a product based off of that with a useEffect hook, for instnace:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Check if product is available or perform
  // a check that you know isn't ready to create yet
  if ( !product ) return;
  (async function run() {
    await createProduct(product);
    setProduct(initialState);
  })()
}, [product])
```

Comment: Hi Colby, thanks for your time. Despite the fact I upload 1 or more files, the final product just returns an array of an empty obj  --> images: [{}]. 
So just testing with 1 file uploaded, and Im not getting the secure_url.
PD: The API gets the image, but not the product state

Comment: Can you inspect the network request for your upload or console log the direct results somewhere? If you're getting a 2XX status I would suspect the issue is with the post-request state management

Your code looks similar to mine here but here I walk through the upload process and have code examples: https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-programmatically-upload-images-to-cloudinary-in-react-next-js/

Comment: Finally I fixed it, I made another button (appart from the submit button) to upload the images, and added useEffect when that input state changes and push those urls to the final IMAGES Array. I dont know if that OK but it works.

Comment: it's certainly okay if it works and works expectedly :) glad to hear you got it going!

Comment: Colby, I'm watching your video of cloudinary w/ NectJS, but is there a way to then delete an image from cloudinary but using fectch or somthing?
Thanks btw for all your help :D

Comment: yup! the admin API has a DELETE endpoint for resources https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources

Comment: Yeah but I need to have installed Cloudinary or something to import, I mean, I can't do it just as your video with fetch

Comment: have you tried? you should be able to use the DELETE endpoint similuarly to how you would use the upload, you pass a method of DELETE instead of POST in your fetch code

there's also the destroy endpoint actually https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#destroy

Comment: Oh, okay I'll try then. But to achieve "cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy" I should have some cloudinary package installed first.

Comment: yup totally. the sdks make it easier to interface but require the packages for sure

Comment: Yeah that's why, so can I npm install cloudinary? or what package do I require? 
PD: Thank you for all your help!. Got a new sub!

Comment: thanks :) what environment are you working in? if you're using node you can use npm install cloudinary. if you're working in the client / browser there are other SDKs such as the URL Gen https://github.com/cloudinary/js-url-gen. if you're uploading, likely youd want to use node on the server or in a serverless function so you can additionally pass in API keys securely

Comment: Im with NextJS so at least "npm install cloudinary" didn't work, or I don't know how to import it or require it.

Comment: Here's an example of how I've done it: https://github.com/colbyfayock/my-camera-filters/blob/main/src/pages/api/upload.js

Comment: The problem is that Im using NextJS and when I require or import "cloudinary" an error is shown, about the module "fs" cant be found. I can't find any solution for deleting cloudinary images with Nextjs

Comment: the example i sent is a serverless function api endpoint where you can securely run the node sdk, i would recommend doing it that way, you dont want to expose your api key in the browser anyways

Comment: Okay Colby, thank you for all your time!.